# How to load two views with different animations when activity starts in android

Tags: android, android-animation, android-transitions

I've an activity with 2 Views. When an activity starts I want that 1st view should slide from TOP while 2nd view should Slide from BOTTOM.

I've followed android tutorials, but the Transition is being applied to entire Activity Layout View rather than individual Views.

I tries using TransitionSet but it didn't work. My Code:

```
TransitionSet set = new TransitionSet();

    View view1 = (View) findViewById(R.id.layout1);
    Transition slideUp = new Slide(Gravity.TOP);
    slideUp.addTarget(view1);
    slideUp.setStartDelay(15000);
    slideUp.setDuration(5000);
    set.addTransition(slideUp);
    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition((ViewGroup)view1, slideUp);


    View view2 = (View) findViewById(R.id.layout2);
    Transition slideDown = new Slide(Gravity.BOTTOM);
    slideDown.addTarget(view2);
    slideDown.setStartDelay(15000);
    slideDown.setDuration(5000);
    set.addTransition(slideDown);
    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition((ViewGroup)view2, slideDown);

    getWindow().setEnterTransition(set);
    getWindow().setExitTransition(set);
```

Where am I commiting error.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ObjectAnimator` to animate your views. This code will translate `view2` in the y direction in 500ms.

```
ObjectAnimator objectAnimator= ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view2, "translationY", 0, -200);
objectAnimator.setDuration(500);
objectAnimator.start();
```

Comment: Thanks my friend, u solved my problem that I was struggling with from a week.